# Python: Reorder a dictionary by the first half/part of the key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I need to reorder a very large OrderedDict by the first 'CSV' of its keys. For example I have a dictionary like this:

```
 a = {'40,70': AAAAAA, '0,12': XXXXXXXX, '20,38': YYYYY}
```

I need it to be ordered on the first number of the key which is always two numbers separated by a comma (I need the second number to then be the ordering factor). The values or Letters are currently of no importance. I need it to be like this:

```
b = {'0,12': XXXXXXXX, '20,38': YYYYY, '40,70': AAAAAA}
```

The dictionary is too big to split each key in a loop - Is there a faster way of doing this?
I have tried to make this as clear as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: dictionaries aren't ordered at least not until 3.6 or officially 3.7. Do you want an `OrderedDict` ?

Comment: "The dictionary is too big to split each key in a loop" unfortunately, you'll have to perform this operation in any sort key you'll use. So why not using a tuple of integers as key directly so you don't need to provide a sort key

Comment: Yes I do need an OrderedDict but that alone will not help. It will not order the items by only 'half' of the key.

Comment: do you need a tiebreaker if the first numbers are equal? this memory requirement is unclear

Comment: Yes I need the second number to then be the ordering factor.

Answer (score 3):

you can use ordered dict to reorder the dict

```
from collections import OrderedDict  
OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda ele:[int(item) for item in ele[0].split(',')]))
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre chang itertiems to items

Comment: `map(int,ele[0].split(',')))` is still not python 3 compliant. You don't need `map` here

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think map is still key word for python3

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I changed map to list comprehensive

Comment: much better. The reason why `map` doesn't work as a sort key is that it returns a generator function, not the expected list. So it doesn't work in python 3 to provide a list key

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  ah, I did not notice it.  thank you

Answer (score 2):

best way would be to create `tuple` keys in your dictionary, then sort using natural order.

If you want to keep the keys as strings, then sort the items of the dictionary into a tuple, with a key function converting the key as a tuple of integers. This provides a tiebreaker in case 2 first numbers are equal:

```
a = {'40,70': "AAAAAA", '0,12': "XXXXXXXX", '0,10': "XXXXXXXX", '20,38': "YYYYY"}

import collections

b = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(),key = lambda e : tuple(map(int,e[0].split(",")))))

print(b)
```

result:

```
OrderedDict([('0,10', 'XXXXXXXX'), ('0,12', 'XXXXXXXX'), ('20,38', 'YYYYY'), ('40,70', 'AAAAAA')])
```

Comment: I was just about to say I forgot to mention that the second half of the key may also be in need of sorting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With 2nd number as tiebreaker:

```
ordered_dict = dict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: [int(x[0].split(",")[0]), int(x[0].split(",")[1])]))
```

Comment: it doesn't sort numerically

Answer (score 0):

I think using OrderedDict you can use something like this.
I am not sure if this is the fastest way.

To sort numerically, I assumed you will always get an integer before comma.

To use second part as second key, and turned the key to a tuple.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = {'40,70': 'AAAAAA', '0,12': 'XXXXXXXX', '20,38': 'YYYYY', '0,38': 'AAYY'}
b = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: (int(x[0].split(',')[0]), int(x[0].split(',')[1]))))
print(b)
```

result is

```
OrderedDict([('0,12', 'XXXXXXXX'), ('0,38', 'AAYY'), ('20,38', 'YYYYY'), ('40,70', 'AAAAAA')])
```

Comment: added int() to convert sorting key to integer

Comment: made changes to use second part of dict keys as the tie breaker

Answer (score -2):

Use OrderedDict

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'40,70': 'AAAAAA', '0,12': 'XXXXXXXX', '20,38': 'YYYYY'}

b = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items()))
```

Comment: it doesn't sort numerically